# Is there a shorthand way to convert an array's items to object properties?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I've been reading through the MDN and seeing all the neat tricks that can be done with the rest and spread operators and array destructuring, and now I'm wondering if there's a way to quickly map array items to named object properties.

I have some plain text tab separated values (copying from a spreadsheet) and right now I've got something more or less like this:

```
const tsv = `1  Jim Robinson    Company Co. Active
2   Fred Jimmyson   Examples Inc.   Inactive
3   Rob Freddison   Company Co. Active`;

const badgeTable = tsv.split('\n').map(e => {
    let tmp = {};
    [ tmp.id, tmp.name, tmp.company, tmp.status ] = e.split('\t')
    return tmp
})
```

Basically, I'm wondering if there's a way to do away with the `tmp` variable I'm using in the map function and directly split the text into an object with the property names.
I tried using the spread operator, like so:

```
const badgeTable = tsv.split('\n').map(e => ({0:id, 1:name, 2:company, 4:status} = {...e.split('\t')}))
```

But it didn't name the properties as I wanted, instead just using the array indexes as property names.

Comment: There's probably a way to do it using `reduce` and an array of the property names.

Comment: @jfriend00 It's tab-separated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` to fill in an object when looping over the array elements.

`reduce()` receives the array index as the third argument, this can be used to index into an array of the property names.

```js
const tsv = `1  Jim Robinson    Company Co.  Active
2   Fred Jimmyson   Examples Inc.   Inactive
3   Rob Freddison   Company Co.  Active`;


const properties = ['id', 'name', 'company', 'status'];
const badgeTable = tsv.split('\n').map(
  line => line.split(/\s{2,}/)
  .reduce((obj, cur, i) => (obj[properties[i]] = cur, obj), {})
);

console.log(badgeTable);
```

I copied @CertainPerformance's hack to split the input lines on multiple spaces.

Answer (score 2):

If you make an array of properties beforehand, you can use `Object.fromEntries` to map each split item to an entry in the object to be created:

```js
const tsv = `1  Jim Robinson    Company Co.  Active
2   Fred Jimmyson   Examples Inc.   Inactive
3   Rob Freddison   Company Co.  Active`;


const properties = ['id', 'name', 'company', 'status'];
const badgeTable = tsv.split('\n').map(
  e => Object.fromEntries(
    e.split(/\s{2,}/)
      .map((value, i) => [properties[i], value])
  )
);

console.log(badgeTable);
```

(I split by `/\s{2,}/` in the above snippet just so that the snippet runs, since Stack Exchange rendered your tabs as spaces and has problems with tab whitespace - your original `\t` will work fine in your actual code)